# Best practice for implementing `on_command_error()` with less boilerplate

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

Typically, `on_command_error()` is implemented using `if`, `elif`, and `isinstance()`.

```py
async def on_command_error(self, ctx: commands.Context, error: commands.CommandError):
    if isinstance(error, commands.NotOwner):
        ...
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        ...
    elif isinstance(error, (commands.UserNotFound, commands.MemberNotFound)):
        ...
```

However, the use of `isinstance(error, ...)` is quite repetitive and cluttering.
So I'm currently experimenting ideas and syntaxes to reduce the boilerplate.

```py
async def on_command_error(self, ctx: commands.Context, error: commands.CommandError):
    match error:
        case commands.NotOwner:
            ...
        case commands.CommandNotFound:
            ...
        case commands.UserNotFound | commands.MemberNotFound:
            ...
```

Coming back from Rust, I tried the `match` statement. It does look a lot cleaner!
It also "semantically" feels like the right tool for the job.
Except... it adds a level of indentation to the entire thing below.

```py
async def on_command_error(self, ctx: commands.Context, error: commands.CommandError):
    try:
        raise error
    except commands.NotOwner:
        ...
    except commands.CommandNotFound:
        ...
    except (commands.UserNotFound, commands.MemberNotFound):
        ...
```

Speaking of *except*, the last thing I tried is raising the command error
and catching it with the `try/except` statement.
It has the advantages of both `isinstance()` and `match`.
Less boilerplate, less indentation.

But it feels illegal to use `try/except` for normal control flows.
Maybe it's ok because it's a normal control flow inside error handling,
so it still counts as an error handling flow? I don't know.

I'm curious about advantages and disadvantages of each choice, how idiomatic it is in Python standard, and if there are other alternative ways to handle this.